# Wpf textbox cannot enter numbers and letters

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

The keyboard cannot enter English and numbers
[window style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWUiy.png)
I have previously set a prohibition on the use of input methods " xmlns:input="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Input;assembly=PresentationCore"
input:InputMethod.IsInputMethodEnabled="False"
But now it’s deleted and you can’t enter numbers and English

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WS_StationManagerPlugin.Forms.FrmMPTable"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cr_utilitywpf="clr-namespace:CR_UtilityWPF;assembly=CR_UtilityWPF"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WS_StationManagerPlugin.Forms"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="FrmTbale"
    Width="800"
    Height="600"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<TextBox
   x:Name="tbxCurrentPage"
   Width="30"
   Margin="5,0,5,0"
   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
   VerticalAlignment="Center"
   Background="#002C41"
   Foreground="#fff"
   KeyDown="tbxCurrentPage_KeyDown"
   PreviewTextInput="tbxCurrentPage_PreviewTextInput"
   TextAlignment="Center">
   <TextBox.ToolTip>
       <ToolTip Content="当前页" />
   </TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>
</Window>
```

Comment: I found that the reason why I can’t enter numbers and letters is that I use the "Show()" method to start the form, and there is no problem using the "ShowDialog()" function.

Comment: ```xaml FrmMPTable frmMPTable = new FrmMPTable();
                    frmMPTable.ShowDialog();```

Comment: Why do different startup methods cause such problems?I hope a master can solve my confusion